# Slider Wordpress plugin search

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins, slider

It's a little bit an unconventional question but I'm trying to find a specific slider in wordpress. The one that is on this website:

> http://www.proulxcommunications.com/portfolio.php

I look in the plugin library since three days and don't find it. Does anyone know or have a trick to know what is this slider plugin.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The site isn't even using WordPress.  The slider is a custom implementation of [jquery.cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the template that they are using, have you checked their source code?

Have you tried Nivo Slider plug-in for WordPress?

Comment: yep i look at it with firebug